# How is the Softlayer ticket group assigned?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is a newly created Softlayer ticket auto assigned into the "SysAdmin" group by default, and then be reviewed and moved to another specific group manually by a Softlayer admin?

During my testing I've tried a couple of different subjects, but the ticket group will always be "SysAdmin" once the ticket is created. So I'm assuming the ticket group has nothing to do with my selected subject/title, but is decided by a Softlayer admin later after the ticket is created.

Please help confirm. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The **groupId** will be automatically assigned, it depends from the **subjectId**, so you will not able to edit this